# Creating installer for a c++ windows service Dynamically

Tags: c++, windows-services, c#-3.0

I have created a windows service which checks for the status of the printer.
The user can download this service from a website. I need to query for the status of printers used by this user. So when the user clicks on the download button I want to store the user information in a file which my service can use. The service will use this information to fetch the printers from the database. I want to include this file in my installer. So I have to create the installer at runtime(i.e. when the user click the download button on my website).

How can I create the installer for the win service dynamically using C#?

NOTE: my win service is written in C++. I know about WIX.

Comment: It sounds easier to put the information on your website, instead of in a file, and have your service download it. It can still cache the data locally.

Comment: Yes , I can do that. But the problem in that case is , my win service will have no idea which user has downloaded it. As the data that the service is gathering is user specific , I want to store it in a file and include that file in the installer. That way the service will collect info for that specific user only. i am open to suggestions though. Please let me know if there are any other simpler methods to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [WiX](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/) you can create [custom actions](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson3.php#3.4) which are arbitrary code you write (You provide the .dll which can be built using C++).  In the [custom action](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson10.php#10.1) you can generate your user/location customization file.

Answer (score 1):

quite a few years ago, when I did some work with `InstallShield`, it was possible to specify in the installer project which file(s) you don't want to be compressed and packed into the `.cab` files (or whatever they are called nowadays) when generating the installation package. Such a file would be left as-is and separate in the package, and you could later replace it with another file with the same name (I think I actually did something of the sort). So you can have a dummy file when building the install package, and then replace it on the fly with the right one.

I am not familiar with modern tools, but am quite sure this functionality is preserved as it is quite useful.